# how to use transform function by mode to fillna after group by dataframe

Tags: mode, fillna

i have a big dataset like:

```
    Log_Time    Log_Date    AL  FROM    TO  Departure_Time  Departure_Date  Price
```

- 0    9:38:32 PM  1395/09/21  18  70.0    15.0    605.0   1395/09/22
  150.2900
- 1    9:38:33 PM  1395/05/01  18  10.0    70.0    2250.0  1395/05/05
  54.9180
- 2   9:38:33 PM   1396/10/08  2   3.0     70.0    2230.0  1396/10/09  72.2296
- 3    9:38:33 PM  1395/04/07  18  75.0    70.0    2200.0  1395/04/11
  67.8452
- 4    9:38:33 PM  1395/04/07  18  75.0    70.0    2200.0  1395/04/11
  89.4056
- 5    9:38:33 PM  1396/05/23  9   70.0    49.0    2000.0  1396/05/26  99.4400

[Flight Ticket Sales Transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW3uJ.png)
I want to fill nulls (of "FROM" col as "FROM2" column) by mode of every group by of other columns.
I can use median like this:

```
df['FROM2'] = df['FROM'].fillna(df.groupby(['TO','AL','Departure_Time','Price'])['FROM'].transform('median'))
```

how to use **mode** instead of **median**?